# 'Missing Auth Token' Response when calling Amazon SP-API

Tags: python, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am attempting to get a successful response from the AMZ SP-API. Below is my current 400 response.

I believe the issue is with the headers. The docs [here](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/listings-items-api-v2021-08-01-reference#getlistingsitem) don't really state what the header contents needs to be.

When I use the SaleWeaver package [here](https://sp-api-docs.saleweaver.com/endpoints/inventories/), I am able to successfully make calls using my AWS and Seller credentials, so I know these work...

FWIW, I am using my 'Merchant Token' as the 'sellerID' PATH value.

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
  'x-amz-access-token': access,
  'client_id': clientid,
  'client_secret':secret,
  'x-amz-date' : '20220402'
}

payload = {'marketplaceId':'ATVPDKIKX0DER'}

sellerId = merch_token
sku = sku

response = requests.get(
  f'https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/listings/2021-08-01/items/{sellerId}/{sku}',
  headers = headers,
  params = payload
)

print(response.text)
```

response:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Access to requested resource is denied.",
     "code": "MissingAuthenticationToken"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header has 4 fields without signing:

```
host: sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com
user-agent: My Selling Tool/2.0 (Language=Java/1.8.0.221;
Platform=Windows/10)
x-amz-access-token=Atza|IQEBLjAsAhRmHjNgHpi0U-Dme37rR6CuUpSREXAMPLE
x-amz-date: 20190430T123600Z
```

If you use AWS SDK, you [don't](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/auth/AWS4Signer.java) need to sign your requests. In your case, you'll have to add an [Authentication](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/connecting-to-the-selling-partner-api#step-4-create-and-sign-your-request) header (which is why it shows missing token right now). With the Auth header, the request looks something like

```
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAIHV6HIXXXXXXX/20201022/us-east-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;user-agent;x-amz-access-token,
Signature=5d672d79c15b13162d9279b0855cfba6789a8edb4c82c400e06b5924aEXAMPLE
host: sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com
user-agent: ...
x-amz-access-token=Atza|IQEBL...
x-amz-date: ...
```

You can read up more on how to calculate the signature and how to add the auth header [here](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/connecting-to-the-selling-partner-api).

Comment: I looked into Python AWS SDK - Boto3 - to use for the signature, and from what I see, it does not support this.   Since I am using Requests, each part of the Authentication header would work in the Requests header= as seperate key/value pairs?

Comment: @anarchocaps no, I think it’s a single pair with comma separated values